# sprite sheets on iPad retina display?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Using cocos2d ,

I know images on regular ipad are using the `-ipad` , and for retina `-ipadhd`
I also know that the **image** of a sprite sheet is the same(`-ipad / -ipadhd`).
But, what with the `plist` files of the sprite sheets ? its also the same suffix as the images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and if you think about it there cannot be any other choice, given the `.plist` file contains the location of each sprite in the sheet, and this will be different for each size sprite sheet.

See this [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32045/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-2-x) from Ray Wenderlich.